# Open Soundcloud From App with Search

Tags: ios, soundcloud

i want to open the soundcloud app from my app:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication]openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"soundcloud://"]]];
```

is it possible to open it with a given string to search for tracks?

could´nt find anything so far.